# Why does prettier want to prefix my IIAFE with ";"?

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

I have had async funcs in my `useEffect` hooks from a javascript project that I am now converting to typescript:

```js
(async ():Promise<void> => {
  const stuff = await doStuff()
  setThings(stuff)
})()
```

Worked without issues before but now in typescript I am getting an error:

```
...
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Replace `(async·():` with `;(async·():·`",
    "source": "eslint",
...
```

Comment: To make sure the parentheses aren't interpreted as an attempt to call what precedes the IIFE. See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi#require-or-disallow-semicolons-instead-of-asi-semi.

Comment: Holy Moly. Mind blown! lol. Wonder why javascript doesn't have that same problem. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: JavaScript *does* have that same problem, I assume your ESLint or Prettier configuration has changed.

Comment: OK that's twice you've blown my mind (have pity!). OK so why are all the examples online so completely devoid of that initial ";" ? Even MDN docs on IIFE don't open with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE hrmm. Perhaps my eslint was too forgiving earlier. Oh well.

Comment: Because the MDN examples all put semicolons at the end of lines, rather than relying on ASI. It's not specific to IIFEs, that's just one of the cases where ASI might not do what you expect.

Comment: !! Ah - I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the response based on @yen's comments- when I enabled semicolons for prettier (and reloaded) it seemed to understand where everything was supposed to be. I suppose I will use semis in JS/TS from now on, it seems to be a best practice anyway.